# UIButton custom class

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

Tengo la siguiente *custom class* de un `UIButton`, pero al agregarla a un botón en Xcode no logro hacer que los cambios se vean reflejados. ¿Alguien sabe cuál es el problema?

```
import UIKit
class BotonBordesRedondeados: UIButton {

    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    /*override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        setup()
    }*/


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }


    func setup () {

        self.layer.backgroundColor = ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#6B00FF") as! CGColor

        self.backgroundColor = ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#6B00FF")

        layer.borderColor = ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#6B00FF").cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 20
        layer.borderWidth = 2.0

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el problema sea un `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`, éste es causado por un *forced downcast* de `UIColor` a `CGColor`. Trata de cambiar el

```
self.layer.backgroundColor = ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#6B00FF") as! CGColor
```

por un

```
self.layer.backgroundColor = ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#6B00FF").cgColor
```

como lo hiciste para el `borderColor`.

(O incluso puedes borrar la instrucción por completo, ya que también le andas asignando el mismo color al `backgroundColor` del `UIView`.)

---

Si el problema es que no se muestran los bordes redondeados, entonces sólo pon dentro de tu `setup()`:

```
layer.maskToBounds = true
```

(O en el *Attributes Inspector* del botón marca la casilla de `Clip to Bounds` en la sección *Drawing*.)

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue sin funcionar, a lo mejor estoy llamando mal la funcion que se lanza al inicio... igual y el button utiliza otra.. por que si pongo el codigo directo del boton.. es decir.. boton.layer..... funciona pero en la class custom no

Comment: El código está bien, ya lo probé y funciona. ¿En el _Identity Inspector_, al seleccionar tu botón en el _Interface Builder_, sí estás asignándole la clase `BotonBordesRedondeados`?

Comment: Hola Gracias, si al parecer ya quedo bien,  lo puse tal como dijiste con el cgColor, y aparte tenia yo un error, tenia repetida una clase con los nombres de los archivos y del class diferente.